# How to create a directory of pdfs that a localhost website can access and display via a link in mariadb?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf, mariadb

This seems like a simple thing to accomplish but the more I've researched the possible avenues to get it done, it gets a bit more blurry, so here goes...

I'm creating a localhost website that will only ever be accessed on a local network, not the WWW. What I'd like to do is have a "library" of pdf books that are accessible via a page containing a search of my mariadb database. Now, I realize storing the actual file in the database is not best practice, so the idea is that the search would render a list of the applicable pdfs based on some criteria in the db, ie - tags, subject, etc. Then, the page would display the results in a table that has a link to open and display the pdf of choice in either an application (like Adobe Reader, Okular etc) or in the browser itself.

Issue is that with a pdf library of nearly 100gb of documents, how do I create a link to a specific pdf without the need to create a page for EVERY document? I'd like the directory of pdfs to be stored on an external drive that the document link can access.

Any help would be great! Thank you in advance for your time and attention! :-)

Comment: Why do you think you would need a page for every document? You just need one script which processes all requests for documents, and accepts something like a document ID as input (via the URL querystring, for example), and then queries the database to find the path of that document, retrieves it and outputs the contents in the response (together with appropriate HTTP headers). So the URL could be something like `https://yourdomain.com/viewdocument.php?id=123` - then when PHP sees the 123 in the "id" parameter, it looks for 123 in the database and retrieves the path to the associated file.

Comment: Thanks folks! So, in doing a bit more research, it seems that there is no way to make a browser open a folder (directory) of files. I like the idea of a reference id number for each document in the database, but the issue seems to be how to get a browser to open a pdf inside a php page? And also it seems the path to the document may still be an issue - example: I have an attached external hard drive housing the pdfs. I've tried the straight link "<a href /media/UbuntuServerExternal/PDFs/ <etcetera>" to open the folder, but it no likey. Seems like workable links are the issue.

Comment: `how to get a browser to open a pdf inside a php page?`... you could use an iframe. Or something like pdf.js

Comment: And `/media/UbuntuServerExternal/PDFs/` isn't a URL, it's a file path. Websites and browsers only deal in URLs (with perhaps the exception of the `file://` protocol which describes a URL scheme which can point to a local path on the client)It wasn't clear from your description whether this drive full of files is supposed to be attached to the server or the client, btw

Comment: ADyson - the idea is that the directory of pdfs resides on the attached storage of the Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu desktop (which is acting as a server)

Comment: Ok. Well then you either need to make the webserver able to read from that folder and return the file in response to getting an ID as input (see my first comment) or you can try outputting links which have `file://` in front of them and point directly to the path on the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks ADyson! So it seems the simplest solution would be the file:// path protocol, though I'm assuming that needs to point to a specific file as opposed to an entire directory, yes? I do like the idea in your first comment, though not sure how I would effect that with 100gb of pdf files. I'm thinking I would have to create an upload page for pdfs going forward and somehow automate the id in the php page?

Comment: `that needs to point to a specific file as opposed to an entire directory`...yes. And you said the whole point would be to open specific PDFs, so I don't really see why you'd want it to open a directory anyway.

Comment: `somehow automate the id in the php page`...you'd need a database table which maps the IDs onto the file path. So you'd have to go through and enter the path of every file into your database. (That itself could be automated as a setup step though, by writing a script which reads the name & path of every file in your storage area and inserts it into the database.). Then you could have a page which reads every entry from the DB and lists them with a link to the viewdocument page I described. That script would take the ID, lookup the path in the DB and fetch the file contents.

Comment: A test case of putting the pdf directory into the /var/www/html directory with the apache2.conf changed to allow access proved successful in getting the browser to open the pdfs folder with links to each document that can then be opened in the browser. It isn't pretty but it works. Question is - can the same thing be accomplished with an external USB drive? That's where I am wondering if moving the stack to the USB drive would make more sense for ease of use and coding

Comment: Yes you can do that - either use the `file://` protocol in your links (will only work when browser and USB drive are on the same machine), or map path from the USB drive as a virtual host in apache, or add the folder via symlink from the /var/www/html folder. There are a few ways you could do it.

Comment: Thanks ADyson! Now to research how to add the USB as a virtual host. The idea is to be able to access the website on a LAN from any device, so it sounds like that may be the best of the two options. Sincerely appreciate the help! Will advise how it goes!

Comment: Yeah if the shared folder is accessible to all the machines which will be using the application then that's one option you can use

Comment: Well I tried adding a directory to the apache2.conf file and that threw an error, so reverted back to trying to find out how to add the usb drive as a virtual host in apache2

Comment: Hey ADyson, so I've successfully mounted the external USB hard drive to /var/www/html/ubuntu_srv. Im able to get a directory listing of */ubuntu_srv/pdfs to open, but when I click on the filename link from the index, the browser goes into download mode on the pdf I select...can't get it to open the pdf in the browser or in a pdf reader application liek Adobe Reader...any ideas as to whether or not this is possible?

Comment: Also, I'm able to get a jpg image from /ubuntu_srv/website_images to show up on the page correctly

Comment: This depends on whether your browser has a PDF reader plugin installed (most do by default these days though) and also whether the server set a `content-disposition` header on the response when it returns file, and what value that header has. It needs to be set to `inline` to prompt the browser to try and display the file inline, if it isn't doing automatically. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition . If you're accesing the files via a direct URL then you likely need to configure Apache to set this header on all PDF files.

Comment: ADyson, I got the pdfs to show up with links! Turns out I had the setting in the browser set to "download"...duh. Now I'm trying to figure out a way to tweak the page so it doesn't look so awful. Been trying to create a php page that will essentially do the same thing as the page showing "index of /pdfs/Biographies" but in a bit less vanilla appearance. I've seen a script in php that uses opendir() function but havent been successful in determining where that php page is supposed to go or the argument that opendir is supposed to take. Examples show "opendir(".") but that isn't working

Comment: Also, since I was able to get the drive mounted as a repository for the pdfs, I realized I didn't need to mess with the sql db at all.

Comment: Glad you got something working. If you have a problem with the opendir stuff specifically, I suggest you start a new post about that then it's open to everyone to take a look and post answers.

Comment: P.S. Yeah I guess you'd only need the database if you have other metadata you'd want to associate with the documents, or want to link them to other information in the database (e.g. make specific documents associate with topics, or particular users, or store extra info about the authors, or whatever.)